# Migrate multiple Access DB (with same function but different data) to single SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, migration, database-migration

**Situation**

I have 5 Access DB files, each one has 10 tables, 40 queries and 8 macros. All 5 Access DB files have same table name, table structure, same queries and same macros. The only **different is the data** contain in the table. If it matters, some tables on each database has rows between few hundreds to 100K+.

**What I am trying to achieve**

I am migrating these 5 Access DB files to single SQL Server (2008) database. ***Edit:*** After migrating, I do need to know which tables belong to which database since each original Access DB is associated with company's department so I need to keep track of this.

**My Solutions or Options**

Tables will be imported to SQL Server as tables. Queries will be imported as Stored Procedures. Macro will be imported as new Stored Procedures.

1. Import each Access DB's tables and queries to SQL Server DB and rename each tables and queries by giving them prefix to identify which tables belong to which database.
2. Same as #1, however, only import tables. As for the queries, only import one set of queries (40 queries) and modify them to *dynamically select, insert, update or delete* from the tables.
3. Import table A from 1st Access DB, table A from 2nd Access DB, table A from 3rd Access DB and so on, to one new table in SQL Server and give them unique identifier to identify which row of data belong to which database.

What do you think is the best approach? Please tell me if there is better way to do this than what I have listed. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you have overlapping primary keys in all tables? You will have to import them into tables with a new primary key and run code to recreate the relationships.

Comment: Another question: do you have to know which row belonged to which database after migrating?

Comment: @cularis The way the Access DB was designed, there was no PK or FK. Yes, thanks for that question, I do need to know which rows belong to which database because each database is associated with one department and I need to keep track of this

Comment: Oh, ok. Maybe this is the time to redesign the database.

Comment: With no PKs/FKs, you don't have a database to begin with. You need to fix that in all five source databases before even beginning to import the data. At the same time, I'd suggest that whatever you implement makes the PKs/FKs unique for each database so they can be imported into a single table in the target database.

Comment: The statement "Macro will be imported as new Stored Procedures" is incoherent. It makes no sense whatsoever, as Macros in Access are primarily for automating UI operations, which are not relevant to the back end data store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would migrate them to MS SQL like so:

- Import all tables from database 1 into corresponding tables from SQL Server, but add a new primary key with the name of the old one, rename the old pk and identifier for the database.
- Update all foreign keys to the new pk field using the old pk and the identifier.
- Repeat for databases 2-5
- Either delete the identifier or keep it, depending if you need to know where the rows came from (same for old primary keys)
- Only import queries/macros once, as they are the same.

When doing it this way, you keep the pk-fk relations and the queries intact and still know where the rows came from.

Comment: Would you put tables from database 2 on the same table as database 1 or create a new one? I assume from your solution to "add a new primary key" you would combine tables from database 1 and 2 through 5 into 1 table.

Comment: Yes, otherwise your solution would only look like one database but really would be 5 databases cramed into one. I guess you want to replace the 5 databases with this one and use it as a central point for your data?

Answer (score 1):

I would say number 3. You would get no duplication code and much easier maintenance.

One example of easier maintenance is performance tuning. You say the queries are the same in the 5 access DBs: say you detect one of the queries runs too slow and you decide that you need to create an index on an underlying table. In option #1 and #2 this would mean recreating the same index on 5 "twin" tables.

Answer (score 0):

In access for each of these databases, you could assign each of the department field id (new field) with it's on identifier in a new table (each department has different value), and then add this value to each of the tables that is to be imported. Create a new table that has the department information in it, then create join table that connect these tables. Thus, each department is differentiated between each other.